# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0" or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I keep getting this Config error everytime I try and upload my website to the server, works fine on localhost

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Line 18:   <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" debug="true">
Line 19:       <assemblies>
Line 20:         <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
Line 21:         <add assembly="MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
Line 22:       </assemblies>
```

I have tried copying the dll's to bin but that didn't work, i've deleted the references and readded in VS2013, rebuilt the project, access the GAC and copied from there...but none of that has worked. Anyone got any suggestions as to what to try next, code from web config is below.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.3.7.0" newVersion="6.8.3.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
  <system.web>

    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
        <add assembly="MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" 
         invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
         description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"  
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MainConnectionString" connectionString="Server=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=Main;Persist Security Info=True;UID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911096/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mysql-web-version-6-8-3-0/29148048#29148048

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help you but I just had a similar problem.
After right clicking in the solution Explorer on the mysql.data.dll and select "include in project" it Works on my webserver... (After republishing of course)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have `MySql.Data.dll` deployed in your project's bind folder or in the web server's GAC.