# How can i export data from mysql database as a code c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I did it but in Mysql workbench , when i tried to do it in the c# application as:

```
string file = "D:\\backup.sql";
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
   using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
 {
   cmd.Connection = myconn;
   mb.ExportToFile(file);
 }
}
```

But it gives error :

Could not load file or assembly `'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d`' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179495/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mysql-data-version-6-8-3-0-or-one-of-its-depe)

Comment: You should install the [MySQL Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html) and make sure you reference `MySql.Data` as a reference in your project.

Comment: i referenced MySQL.data
I will check connector

THanks